# Regular expression and removing parentheses

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe`:

```
name
(John)
(Lily)
(Eddy)
Wang
Lisa
```

The `dataframe` is not correctly formatted and I need to remove the parentheses.
The returned `df` should be:

```
name
John
Lily
Eddy
Wang 
Lisa
```

My code is:

```
merge_df['name'] = merge_df['name'].replace('()','')
```

But the returned `df` doesn't give me the result I wanted. Anyone knows how to fix this piece of code?

Comment: @MZ No need to escape `()` inside `[]` they loose there special meaning

Answer (score 1):

`.replace` is by default looks for exact matching.  You can specify explicitly that you want to use regular expression as below.

```py
merge_df['name'].replace(regex="[()]", value="")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), the first parameter of the `replace` function is a string to be replaced.
Therefore, the `some_str.replace('()','')` means replace all the `()` in your string, which is not found, and hence your replace function returned the same string back.

There are three ways to deal with it.

1. Using multiple replace functions.

   Since you can only replace on kind of substring at one time, we can use it twice to fulfill our purpose.

   ```
   your_str = your_str.replace('(','').replace(')','')
   ```
2. Using regular expression library `re.sub()`.

   The `re.sub()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.sub)) function is much more powerful to specify different substring to be replaced in one call.

   **For me, I prefer this solution, since it is more flexible and powerful.**

   ```
   import re
   your_str = re.sub(r'[\)\(]', '', your_str)
   ```
3. Using `str.strip()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip))

   The `str.strip()` function will only remove the **characters** on the ends of your string, and you can also specify **multiple character** you want to remove.
   Therefore, in this case, it is useful.

   ```
   your_str = your_str.strip('()')
   ```

Comment: This is a good answer. I would suggest an inversion of the preference, however: start simple (eg `strip` and `replace`) and resort to higher-level tools (eg, regex) only when you know the need will exist fairly soon.